# jmonkey shows blackscreen with blender models

Tags: blender, jmonkeyengine

So I build a model of a tank in blender which I implemented later on in jmonkey with a spatial. But when I gave the model texture, materials and morde detail, jmonkey responds with an error "NullPointerExeption" and closes the test application which ended as a blackscreen before.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Please post a stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jme3.export.binary.BinaryImporter.readObject(BinaryImporter.java:314)
at com.jme3.export.binary.BinaryImporter.load(BinaryImporter.java:242)
at com.jme3.export.binary.BinaryImporter.load(BinaryImporter.java:125)
at com.jme3.export.binary.BinaryImporter.load(BinaryImporter.java:109)
at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadLocatedAsset(DesktopAssetManager.java:259)
at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadAsset(DesktopAssetManager.java:373)
at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadModel(DesktopAssetManager.java:416)
at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadModel(DesktopAssetManager.java:420)
at mygame.Main.makeScene(Main.java:122)
at mygame.Main.simpleInitApp(Main.java:56)
at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:220)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:211)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What software was used to add the texture? It shouldn't react like this, but it looks like the format is something unexpected. You could try using other software to create assets or experiment with export settings/formats.